# WORDPRESS how i can use AJAX to get POSTS

Tags: ajax, wordpress

wordpress in loop.php I have three inputs type radio:
 1-filter posts  by date
 2-filter by count views
 3-filter by comments

how i can use ajax to get these filters?

this is my code

```
<div class="filter">
   <form action="#" id="form-filter">
          <input type="radio" id ="listing-1" name="filters" value="recents" checked><label for="listing-1">the must recent</label>
          <input type="radio" id ="listing-2" name="filters" value="views"><label for="listing-2">the must views</label>
          <input type="radio" id ="listing-3"  name="filters" value="comments"><label for="listing-3">the must comments</label>
      </form>
</div>
```

and this is the code php

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
       the_post(); 

       //the_post_thumbnail
       // Post Content here


   } // end while
  } // end if
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: 1. Think, 2. Type, 3. Execute.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly before learning how you can do in Wordpress, you need to learn how AJAX works. You're in the very begining of AJAX based application development.

Secondly, for sure there's no limit for how you want to implement your project; but it's suggested to use admin-ajax based functionality.

It's also suggested to learn about usage of nonce for data security. There're for sure many other things. Please do a massive search and read a lot of examples.